# Convert IF-ELSE statement in Linear Programming (ORTools)

Tags: linear-programming, or-tools

I am trying to create an Optimization for Gas Storage using Linear Programming (OR Tools).
I need to write a case like this:

```
if current_balance > 70% of Total Volume:
    set a limit for gas injection as 10
else:
    set a limit for gas injection as 30
```

Current balance is the Total amount of gas that is available today in a gas storage.

I tried looking at Big M notation.

Is there other way except Big M? And if i have to use Big M then how can I use it in above problem?

Edited:
How can i build equation for following case:

```
if current_balance > 70% of Total Volume and current_balance < 80% of Total Volume:
    set a limit for gas injection as 10
else if current_balance > 80% of Total Volume:
    set a limit for gas injection as 30
```

Comment: What is the value supped to be for `current_balance <= 70%` in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an other way but Big M, although Big M get much better when you put some thought into it and choose M wisely and not too big (as small as possible). When the current balance is never allowed to exceed the total volume the following formulation is the tightest to work for you case. Here exceed is a boolean variable indicating whether you are exceeding the 70% of the total volume.

- current_balance - (30%TotalVolume)*exceed <= 70%TotalVolume
- gas_injection <= 30 - 20*exceed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried Big M method for my problem. It worked for the above case. But i could not derive equation for multiple case.
i.e. 
`if current_balance > 70% of Total Volume and current_balance < 80% of Total Volume:`
`    set a limit for gas injection as 10`
`else if current_balance > 80 % of Total volume:`
`    set a limit for gas injection as 5`

Any help on this?

Comment: This description differs from the way you modified your question. Can you double check the question? And maybe add the missing case for `current_balance <= 70%`?